# Criteria for positive semi-definiteness - zero diagonal

Tags: analysis, matrices

I am currently doing a bit of background reading on some fundamental topics in preparation for a talk, and came across a question relating to positive definiteness. It is taken from Horn and Johnson's book entitled Matrix Analysis, and reads as follows:

Show that if a positive semidefinite matrix has a zero entry on the main diagonal, then the entire row and column to which it belongs must be zero. (See page 400)

At first glance, this seemed a straightforward problem, so i'm pretty certain i'm missing something obvious. I have tried writing out various expansions, and playing with different characterisations as given in previous exercises/corollaries - all to no avail. If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be most helpful!

Best,
Chris

Answer (score 3):

Let the elements of your matrix $A$ be denoted as $a_{ij}$ and assume that $a_{kk} = 0$ for some $k$. Further, let $a_{ik} \ne 0$ for some $i \ne k$. Since $A = A^T$, we know that $a_{ik} = a_{ki}$. Now observe the principal submatrix spanned by the elements with indexes $k,i$, i.e.,

$$B := \begin{bmatrix} a_{ii} & a_{ik} \\ a_{ki} & a_{kk} \end{bmatrix}.$$

This is a bit imprecise, as I've written it as if though $i < k$, but the case $i > k$ is the same.

What can you say about $\det B$?